# How to warp text to simulate paper curl effect, in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I have an object with some perspective, to simulate a paper curl effect (blue sticker on image below).

[image]

How do I apply the same effect to text (i.e., how do I make the purple text look like it is part of the sticker)?

I guess I must find a way to curve my object on the z axis, but, I have no idea how to do that.

---

**Here is what I tried:**

- I started to create an outline of the text (Type > Create Outline).
- From there, I tried to play with Envelope Distort Actions (Make with Warp, Make with Mesh, Make with Top Object).

Make with Top Object sounded the most close to what I need, but either it's not the right tool, either I don't get how to use it.

- Menu Effect > Warp: none of the actions are what I'm looking for. Some are close, but only by chance.
- Menu 3D : seems like it will extrude me a shape, not at all what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a Mesh Envelope Distort. The easiest way to ensure that the text follows the same contours as the sticker is to recreate the sticker shape. In this case, it's very easy since the un-warped dotted-line "shadow" of the sticker will give us a good base line.

### Step 1: Re-create the Surrounding shape and Group it with Your Text

[image: Re-create the surrounding shape]

### Step 2: Create a Mesh Envelope Distort

*Specify 1 Row and 1 Column. I reduced the opacity of the re-created shape to make things easier*

[image: Create a Mesh Envelope Distort]

### Step 3: Manipulate the Anchors and Handles to Match the Curled Shape

*It doesn't have to be perfect if you're only doing this for the text*

[image: Manipulate the Anchors and Handles to Match the Curled Shape]

## Step 4: Edit the Mesh Contents to Remove the Re-Created Shape

*This will leave you with your finished product*

[image]

You can tweak it as necessary to give it more depth, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is pretty much it and thumbs up for the using the concept of `registration` ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_registration )